# Disassembling: Why a jmp that leads nowhere?

Tags: assembly

I'm trying to understand what a C program (a binary bomb) does using only its object file. I have jmp command in the middle of a function that doesn't seem to lead anywhere:

```
   8048c4b:     cmp    $0x1,%eax
   8048c4e:     jg     8048c55 <phase_3+0x31>
   8048c50:     call   804937c <explode_bomb>
31:8048c55:     cmpl   $0x7,0x18(%esp)
   8048c5a:     ja     8048cc2 <phase_3+0x9e>
   8048c5c:     mov    0x18(%esp),%eax
   8048c60:     jmp    *0x804a4bc(,%eax,4)   //here is the weird jmp
   8048c67:     mov    $0x0,%eax
   8048c6c:     jmp    8048c73 <phase_3+0x4f>
   8048c6e:     mov    $0x1a1,%eax
4f:8048c73:     sub    $0x19b,%eax
   8048c78:     jmp    8048c7f <phase_3+0x5b>
```

Meanwhile the highest address in the disassembly is 0x804a315. Does anyone know what this could be?
Edit: The function takes 2 user-input numbers, if they are the right ones, a phase of the bomb gets defused.

Comment: Possibly a chunk in a data segment that contains assembled code?

Comment: Insufficient data...can you give a more peek of your fump? And a little more description of its origin?

Comment: What if `%eax` is negative?

Comment: @par Are there ways to look at what is in that data segment?

Comment: You can usually disassemble from an arbitrary address, you'll have to read the docs for your disassembler.

Comment: The disassembly looks GNUish so I guess you are getting it from `objdump -d`. That's fine for examining code; to examine data, you probably want `objdump -s`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an indirect jump through a jump table (notice the leading `*`). The jump table just holds some addresses, it's not in a code section, you can't disassemble it. You can however look at its contents.

Comment: Jester, help me grasp this: So it's like eax, shifted 4 with an offset of 0x804a4bc ?

Comment: It's multiplied by 4, because a pointer is 4 bytes. The jump table starts at address `0x804a4bc`.

Comment: got it; The Nth element of the table at `0x804A4BC` Yes ?

Comment: Yes, with `N` being in `eax`.