# What is the jmpq command doing in this example

Tags: assembly, terminal, gdb, att

We are using gdb debugger to read assembly functions.

In assembly, we have the following instructions:
`mov    0xc(%rsp),%eax`
`jmpq   *0x402390(,%rax,8)`

At memory location `*0x402390` we have the value `0x8e`. In register rax, we have the second integer input for this particular function (could use variable y).

From our analysis, we have deduced that this function takes in three variables `(x, y, z)` and that they can be found at memory location `(rsp)`, `(rsp + 8)`, `(rsp + 12)` respectively.

We would like to know what is going on in `jmpq   *0x402390(,%rax,8)`.
Is it jumping to the instruction at `(0x8e + rax*8)`? If so, how can we find out what that instruction is called?

This is the full dump of assembler code for the function phase_3:

[image: Full assembly function]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does the jmp instruction work in att assembly in this instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23418524/how-does-the-jmp-instruction-work-in-att-assembly-in-this-instance). See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26204974/disassembling-why-a-jmp-that-leads-nowhere/26205216)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the [GAS-manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/):

> An Intel syntax indirect memory reference of the form
>
> ```
>  section:[base + index*scale + disp]
> ```
>
> is translated into the AT&T syntax
>
> ```
>  section:disp(base, index, scale)
> ```
>
> where base and index are the optional 32-bit base and index registers,
>   disp is the optional displacement, and scale, taking the values 1, 2,
>   4, and 8, multiplies index to calculate the address of the operand.

(https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dMemory.html#i386_002dMemory)

So you can translate `jmpq *0x402390(,%rax,8)` into INTEL-syntax: jmp [RAX*8 + 0x402390]. It's an "indirect" jump. At address [RAX*8 + 0x402390] is an address which will become the target of `jmp`. The next step is to determine, how many addresses can be found at 0x402390 + x and in which case they are used.

Answer (score 24):

Bomb-lab right lol?

This operation `jmpq *0x402390(,%rax,8)` is for jumping directly to the absolute address stored at
`8 * %rax + 0x402390`

If you do `x/16gx 0x402390` in gdb (inspect 16 "giant words" in hexadecimal starting at `0x402390`) you will find an address table looks like the following:(i have a different lab so it's not the same as yours)

```
 0x402880:  0x0000000000400fee  0x000000000040102b
 0x402890:  0x0000000000400ff5  0x0000000000400ffc
 0x4028a0:  0x0000000000401003  0x000000000040100a
 0x4028b0:  0x0000000000401011  0x0000000000401018
```

Where all these addresses all point back to the a single `mov` operation immediately after `jmpq *0x402390(,%rax,8)`

Comment: hah it's been four years since I posted about this and almost 2 years out of college now :p

Comment: @MichaelGofron : and in all those years you never accepted an answer to this question despite the fact rkhb gave a proper answer.If you were to accept an answer, possibly others may be less inclined to add new answers years later? ;-)

Comment: Yeah, but at this point I don't even remember if that was the right answer to my question now because I've lost the context of how it worked

Comment: thank you my fellow Northwesterner @MichaelGofron

Answer (score 1):

It's jumping into a table of code that has 8 bytes per entry, sort of like a switch case statement optimization. It's a bit confusing because there is a series of 7 byte sequences just after the jmpq, and the code that the jmpq branches to (starting at 402390) is not shown in the image.